# Преобразование файла Excel в таблицу HTML (с форматом)

Tags: html, excel, синтаксический-анализ

Есть вот такая страница:
Скрытый текст (вы должны войти под своим логином или зарегистрироваться и иметь 1 сообщение(ий)): У вас нет прав, чтобы видеть скрытый текст, содержащийся здесь.
На ней есть кнопки "Скачать Excel" (со ссылками).
Возле них есть кнопки "Показать", где открывается тот же файл, только преобразованный в html формат (пока это все делается вручную).

Вопрос: можно ли как-то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Подсказали, вроде парсерами можно реализовать, но, честное слово, не представляю даже, что это такое.
Если имеются знатоки в этом нелегком вопросе, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Буду ОЧЕНЬ признателен!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel, https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/